# kubernetes ingress returns incorrect mimetype on rewrite-target

Tags: kubernetes, mime-types, kubernetes-ingress, content-type

I am having a problems with content response from a k8s version: `1.20.15`, the ingress redirects to 2 applications based on the same domain (domains bellow are hypothetical). One service being an API and the other a website.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: frontend-explorer
  name: frontend-explorer
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev-explorer.test.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-explorer-svc
            port:
              number: 8081
      - path: /api/(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-explorer-svc
            port:
              number: 3000
```

A request like `dev-explorer.test.org/api/settings` will be forward to the `backend-explorer-svc` and its url will become `dev-explorer.test.org/`, to the backend service

The services seem to working without any problems, but when accessing `https://dev-explorer.test.org`, there are errors like:

```
Loading module from “https://dev-explorer.test.org/main-es2015.3c58a0782b71050b1782.js” 

was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

You can use a curl to fetch the content, but the ingress responds with
`content-type: text/html` instead of `content-type: application/js`, forcing the browser to block the website

Not certain if this is a problem on the ingress, or the JS code it self. Any ideas on how to get the correct `content-type` ?

Comment: Jorge - did you ever resolve this?  I also have a kubernetes cluster with ingress and a vue application that has the same error.  If i run the docker container locally or within Azure Web Apps, it runs fine.  So this seems to be a problem with Nginx Ingress Controller only

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the ingress was responding with `content-type: text/html` as if it was dealing with a [pre-flight CORS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) The solution was to **disable CORS on ingress** and configure it on the app.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ...
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "false"
    ...
```

Comment: i malso facing same error with nginx ingres, but disabling CORS not worked for me. any solution?